# How to configure a ServletContextListener programmatically in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, servletcontextlistener

I'd like to configure one or more ServletContextListener's programmatically, that is, without configuring them via web.xml. I'm currently doing something similar by adding servlets and filters programmatically.

Is this possible? If so, could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Tomcat 7 you have two options to avoid web.xml. The first is to use the @WebListener annotation but I suspect that isn't quite what you want. The second it so use a ServletContainerInitializer (SCI). For an exmaple, see how [Tomcat's WebSocket SCI](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/archive/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_47/java/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/server/WsSci.java?view=annotate) does it. That SCI does a lot of things. The relevant line for you is `servletContext.addListener(new WsContextListener());`

Note that an SCI uses the services API to [register itself](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/archive/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_47/res/META-INF/tomcat7-websocket.jar/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer?view=annotate).

Comment: Thanks Mark, exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find in any of the Tomcat documentation.

Comment: That is as I would expect. Generally (there is the odd exception), the Tomcat documentation doesn't repeat anything that is in the Servlet specification.

Comment: Is it really repeating the Servlet spec? Actually implementing this is pretty specific to, well, the implementating container.

Comment: Yes, this is repeating the Servlet spec. It isn't at all container specific.

Comment: These links are now dead, which is why (in addition to links), it's good to put the important content of links inline in the answer. This answer is now incomplete.

Comment: I've fixed the links.